# Testing presence of one outcome over another

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, categorical-data

I have what I think is a simple problem, but I can't seem to think of how to test it.

I have a sample of 2649 patients, of whom 125 have a specific disease.  The disease is classified into "early" and "late", and I want to test the difference between the probability of being "early" vs "late", and, if possible, calculate a relative risk.

I can get the probabilities easily enough, and I can get the ratio of the probabilities to get a relative risk.  My question is how do I test these variables or get confidence intervals: since both outcomes are from the same population the equations I'm used to don't work.

Thanks in advance, I've included some simple sample R code below.

```
sample = c(rep(0,2517),rep('A',68),rep('B',64))
p = c(sum(sample=='A'),sum(sample=='B'))/length(sample)
RR = p[1]/p[2]
```